# TypeScript/React how does scan operator work where currentvalue = function interface?

Tags: reactjs, function, typescript, rxjs, accumulator

I have a scan operator with the following arguments:

```
.scan(function (acc:Message[], x: (msg: Message[]) => Message[]){ return x(acc); }, initialMessages)
```

my question is what `return x(acc)` returns actually? how does the accumulator `function` work in this particular case?
I am quite new to TypeScript and lambda expressions, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the type of `x(acc)` would be `Message[]`. You can tell this from the signature of the 2nd argument `x`, which returns `Message[]`.

Usually `scan()` accepts a function `(acc, val) => ...` with accumulator and value. and emits the returned value. In this case the emitted value `val` entering the scan operator is a closure. it's a bit unusual, but perfectly fine. An example which outputs

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
```

...would be:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

type Message = number;

function scanFn(acc: Message[], x: (msg: Message[]) => Message[]): Message[] {
  return x(acc);
}

function mapFn(val: Message): (msg: Message[]) => Message[] {
  return x => x.map((y, i) => val + i);
}

Observable.from([1, 3, 4])
  .map(mapFn)
  .scan(scanFn, [1, 2, 3])
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Interesting example. To put another way, for each element of input [1, 3, 4] we create a function using map operator which is then used as an input arg (x) for scanFn:

Comment: so for the last element (=4) of [1, 3, 4] input array, scan operator will emit this:</br>
`return x(acc) = acc.map(function (y, i) { return val + i; }) =[1, 2, 3].map(function (y, i) { return val + i; }) = [1, 2, 3].map(function (y, i) { return 4 + i; }) // i = index values 0, 1, 2.. = [4+0, 4+1, 4+2] = [4, 5, 6]`.
</br>
Great! Thanks again!